# 2D-Array : prefered way access items

Tags: java, c++, c, coding-style

So here I am tonight with this question that came up into my mind :

What is your favourite way to access the items of a m x n matrix

there is the normal way where you use an index for the columns 
and another index for the rows matrix[i][j]

and there's another way where your matrix is a vector of length m*n
and you access the items using [i*n+j] as index number

tell me what method you prefeer most , are there any other methods 
that would work for specific cases ?

Comment: I believe you would like to get opinions regarding arrays in Java, C++, or C, but note that 2d-arrays in programming languages could be different, such as C# and Python. So I guess it's a good idea to specify languages you would especially like to look at.

Comment: of course, I thought that this would have been self intended from the tags I've used :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two reasons to go for the one-dimensional array to represent n-dimensions I can think of:

- Performance: The usual way to allocate n-dimensional arrays means that we get n dimensions that may not necessarily be allocated in one piece - which isn't that great for spatial locality (and may also result in at least some additional memory accesses - in the worst case we need 1 additional read for each access). Now in C/C++ you can get around this (allocate memory in one piece, then afterwards specify the correct pointers; just be really careful not to forget this when you delete it) and other languages (C#) already can do this out of the box. Also note that in a language with a stop&copy GC the reasoning is unnecessary since all the objects will be allocated near each other anyhow. You avoid additional overhead for each single dimension though, so you use your memory and cache a bit better.
- For some algorithms it's nicer to just use a one dimensional array which may make the code shorter and slightly faster - that's probably the one thing that can be argued as subjective here.

Comment: It is important to note that in c and c++ `int **ary` is *not* a 2d array. You *can* access it with `ary[i][j]`, but that is syntactic sugar. Yes, multiple allocations with a `**` are common, but you *can* do `int (*ary)[3][5] = malloc(sizeof int[3][5]);` to get a real 2d array allocated on the heap.

Comment: About your malloc trick: Fascinating, but obviously only useful if you have compiletime constants which is mostly not the case (and I can't correctly cast the malloc result on VC++ and it won't compile without it even in C mode). And it probably depends on how you define "n-dim array" - language agnostic I'd go with something like "Collection of elements that are indexed by N indizes" or something - in which case arr[i][j] does qualify ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have this piece of C(++) code:

```
 int x = 3;
 int y = 4;

 arr2d[x][y]   = 0xFF;
 arr1d[x*10+y] = 0xFF;
```

Where:

```
 unsigned char arr2d[10][10];
 unsigned char arr1d[10*10];
```

And now let's look at the compiled version of it (assembly; using debugger):

[image]

As you can see there's absolutely no penalty or slowdown when accessing array elements no matter if you're using 2D arrays or not, since both of the methods are actually the same.

Comment: You should try that again for arrays not allocated on the stack - those have some different rules. If you're only talking about stack allocated arrays you're right - multidimensional arrays are nothing more than syntactical sugar for a larger one-dimensional. Same is not true for the general case and that may have performance repercussions.

Comment: Indeed. This rule applies only for the stack-allocated cases. Using '2D' arrays allocated in heap does require less time to process (except for the initialization) and does generate less code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you need a 2D array, is because you would like to access it as a 2d array, not as a 1D array

Otherwise you can do a simple multiply to make it a 1D array

Answer (score 0):

If I was to use a 2-D array, I would vote for matrix[i][j]. I think this is more readable. However, I might consider using Guava's Table class.
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your "favourite" way, or the most aesthetically pleasing way is a good approach to take with this issue - underlying performance would be my main concern.

Storing a matrix as a contiguous array is often the most efficient way of doing matrix calculations. If you take a look at optimised BLAS (Basic Linear Algebra Subroutine) libraries, such as the Intel MKL, the AMD ACML, ATLAS etc etc contiguous matrix storage will be used. When contiguous storage is used, and contiguous data access patterns are exploited higher performance can result due to the improved locality-of-reference (i.e. cache performance) of the operations.

In some languages (i.e. `c++`) you could use operator overloading to achieve the `data[i][j]` style of indexing while doing the 1D array index mappings behind the scenes.

Hope this helps.